# It is unnecessary to trace all recursive invocations of a function

Tags: c, recursion

I found an article, [The secret to understanding recursion](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/03/30/understanding-recursion/), which left me very confused. It suggests that it is unnecessary to trace all the invocations of a recursive function. It also says:

> A programmer defining a recursive function usually does not think explicitly about the sequence of invocations that results from calling it.

I do not understand this. Can you explain?

Comment: I think that it is saying that normally you don't think about the full invocation chain for a recursive function (especially since it is potentially unbounded), but just to the base case and a generic n-th step (plus maybe the first call when there's some setup to do). I can confirm that rarely I got any particular insight in recursive problems by stepping in each and every invocation - although seeing the first/last few stack frames may help.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: If the recursion isn't bounded, there's going to be trouble.

Comment: Just because somebody wrote a blog post saying X, Y, or Z doesn't make it so. If I write a blog post that says "Everybody should send Bob one million dollars" are you gonna do it? (*Please say yes!!!* :-). Personally I think that tracing through a couple examples of recursion is a good way to show how and why the recursive functions work. Think for yourself.

Comment: @BobJarvis That's kind of a condescending way to say, "I disagree with the article."

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis: I had my doubts the article was somewhat doubtful therefore I decided to write here for ask

Comment: Maybe the point of the article is similar to mathematical induction, where you prove some relationship true for a specific case, then devise a method to prove that if the relationship is true for n, then it's also true for n+1. Similar to the article, you don't need to test every case. However, if a recursive function is not working, you often have to debug a simple case situation, perhaps displaying data with each level of recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context, he’s saying that, as long as each step gets you closer to the base case, you’re going to get there, and you don’t need to do a step-by-step walkthrough of the algorithm to realize that.

You might have seen factorials as an example?  If you know that the *n*! = *n*×(*n*-1)! step is correct, and you know that the 1! = 1 step is correct, you don’t need to do all the arithmetic to get from  10! = 10×9! down to 10! = 10×9×8 ... in order to verify the algorithm.  Since each step is correct, and *n* gets smaller each time, you’re going to get to the base case and you can prove it just from that.

Comment: A programmer does have to think explicitly about the base case, and perhaps the next layer(s) just above the base case. Recursive Fibonacci might be a better example, since it self calls twice for each level of recursion, .... return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

Comment: *E.g.* Knuth’s famous warning, “I have only proved this code correct, not tested it?”

Comment: But yes, a proof by induction has two parts: the proof of the base case and the proof of the induction step.  If you also want to prove the algorithm terminates, you have to prove that some quantity from a well-founded set gets closer to the base case with each step.  In this instance, that’s *n* itself, decreasing to 1.

Comment: In some cases, the recursive process is a bit more complicated, such as traversal of a tree where any node can be a leaf or a node to a list of nodes, or something similar such as the directory structure on a hard drive  partition. This is a case where debugging generally involves confirming that the entire tree was traversed and in the desired order (depth first or width first).

Comment: Right.  But you don’t prove correctness by walking through steps; you prove it by showing that the number of untraversed nodes decreases to zero, or something.  This isn’t the right venue to argue about whether the article was correct, but that’s what its thesis is.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a programmer to define a recursive function, usually at some point in time prior to defining a recursive function, a programmer would usually want to understand how recursion works, but the article seems focused on how to define a recursive function, as opposed to understanding how recursion works, despite the articles title. So in my opinion, the articles title is a bit mis-leading.

As already commented, in order to understand recursion, usually a simple recursive function is used as a learning example (factorial, Fibonacci, ...). A programmer doesn't need to trace through every level, but may consider what happens a few levels just above the base case, and also the initial case and down one or two levels.

Once recursion is understood, then defining a function just needs to follow the rules mentioned in the article.